# Bitwise-or seems to have an implicit cast to long. Can this be avoided?

Tags: c#, casting, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm a Java programmer trying to migrate to C#, and this gotcha has me slightly stumped:

```
int a = 1;

a = 0x08000000 | a;
a = 0x80000000 | a;
```

The first line compiles just fine. The second does not. It seems to recognise that there is a constant with a sign bit, and for some reason it decides to cast the result to a long, resulting in the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The fix I have so far is:

```
a = (int)(0x80000000 | a);
```

Which deals with the cast but still leaves a warning:

> Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand;
>   consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first

What would be the correct C# way to express this in an error/warning/long-free way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A numeric integer literal is an `int` by default, unless the number is too large to fit in an `int` and it becomes an `uint` instead (and so on for `long` and `ulong`).

As the value 0x80000000 is too large to fit in an `int`, it's an `uint` value. When you use the `|` operator on an `int` and an `uint` both are extended to `long` as neither can be safely converted to the other.

The value can be represented as an int, but then you have to ignore that it becomes a negative value. The compiler won't do that silently, so you have to instruct it to make the value an `int` without caring about the overflow:

```
a = unchecked((int)0x80000000) | a;
```

(Note: This only instructs the compiler how to convert the value, so there is no code created for doing the conversion to `int`.)

Comment: No, it's `uint`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, that looks like the neatest fix. Thanks.

Comment: And for code-tidyness because I have a lot of masks:

private const int MASK_80000000 = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

Comment: @Johannes: That is true. I corrected that, and also specified where the conversion to long happens.

Answer (score 13):

I find it interesting that in all these answers, only one person actually suggested *doing what the warning says*. The warning is telling you how to fix the problem; pay attention to it.

> Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first

The bitwise or operator is being used on a sign-extended operand: the int. That's causing the result to be converted to a larger type: long.  An unsigned type smaller than long is uint. So do what the warning says; cast the sign-extended operand -- the int -- to uint:

```
result = (int)(0x80000000 | (uint) operand);
```

Now there is no sign extension.

Of course this just raises the larger question: why are you treating a signed integer as a bitfield in the first place? This seems like a dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because 0x80000000 is a minus in int form and you cannot perform bitwise operations on minus values.

It should work fine if you use a uint.

```
a = ((uint)0x80000000) | a;  //assuming a is a uint
```

Comment: `0x80000000` is already `uint`, according to the specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: That makes no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: This explanation is bogus. You can perform bitwise operations on negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Changing that line to
`(int)((uint)0x80000000 | (uint)a);`
does it for me.

Comment: That seems to do the trick :)
Anyone know if those casts come with a runtime cost? Or does the compiler tidy it all up sensibly?

Comment: The underlying runtime system doesn't make a distinction between int and uint; it's just a bucket of 32 bits. Casts will be jitted away to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that

- `0x80000000` is an *unsigned* integer literal. The specification says that an integer literal is of the first type in the list (`int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`) which can hold the literal. In this case it is `uint`.
- `a` is *probably* an `int`

This causes the *result* to be a `long`. I don't see a nicer way other than cast the result back to `int`, unless you know that `a` can't be negative. Then you can cast `a` to `uint` or declare it that way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it less ugly by creating a constant that starts with the letter 'O'. (And unlike on this website, in visual studio, it doesn't show it in a different color).

```
const int Ox80000000 = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

/// ...

const int every /*  */ = Ox80000000;
const int thing /*  */ = 0x40000000;
const int lines /*  */ = 0x20000000;
const int up /*     */ = 0x10000000;
```